# insert when one value is selected from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to `insert` new values into a table `where` one of the values is being selected from another table with a condition, and the other value is a constant (hardcoded)

this command gives a syntax error

```
INSERT INTO table1 (itemId, reservedId) VALUES (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition, 213) ;
```

error message : syntaxe error at line 2

Comment: ___This command gives a syntax error___ Its always useful to show us the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (itemId, reservedId) 
     SELECT id, 123
     FROM table2
     WHERE condition ;
```

No `VALUES` is needed.

Comment: Congrats of breaking the 1M rep barrier!

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix values and select statements like this, as you've seen. You could, however, select the literal values you want to insert from the same table (note that you should not have a `values` clause - it's replaced by the `select` statement):

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (itemId, reservedId)
SELECT id, 213 FROM table2 WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

`insert into yourtable(...) values(...)[, (...)...]`

or

```
insert into yourtable(...) select ...
```

Your mistake was that you mixed up the two syntaxes. You will not need `values(...)` here wrapped around your `select`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (itemId, reservedId) 
SELECT id, 213 
FROM table2 
WHERE condition;
```

Notice that 213 is a value for `reservedId` and has nothing to do in the `where` clause.